# Graph Laplacian quadratic form, unusual notation

Tags: graph-theory, graph-laplacian

I have following task:
Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix and $L$ the Laplacian matrix of a simple undirected connected graph $G$.
Show that for an arbitrary vector of real numbers $x \in \Bbb R^n$ the graph Laplacian associates the following quadratic form with the graph $G$:

$$x^T\!Lx = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j} A_{ij} (x_i - x_j)^2$$

---

I have studied some literature on the Laplacian and its quadratic form, but the nearest I could get to was $$x^T\!Lx = \sum_{i,j} A_{ij} (x_i - x_j)^2.$$

So please could somebody enlighten me on where the $1/2$ term comes from?

Comment: It’s just a convention. There are two ways to turn a matrix into a quadratic form and they differ by a factor of $2$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, could you elaborate how this specific way would look like?

Comment: You can associate to a matrix $M$ either the quadratic form $x^T M x$ or the quadratic form $\frac{1}{2} x^T M x$. Over the real numbers it doesn't really matter which choice you make but over the integers the two choices change which quadratic forms you regard as being "integral."

Answer (score 6):

The 1/2 factor comes from the fact that you count every edge twice in the sum (as (i,j) and then as (j,i)). The computation is

$$\sum_{i,j} A_{i,j} (x_i-x_j)^2 = \sum_{i,j} A_{i,j} x_i^2 + \sum_{i,j} A_{i,j} x_j^2 - 2\sum_{i,j} A_{i,j} x_ix_j.$$

The first two terms can be summed using the degree $D_{ii} = \sum_{j} A_{ij}$ to obtain

$$\sum_{i,j} A_{i,j} (x_i-x_j)^2 = \sum_{i} D_{ii}x_i^2 + \sum_{j} D_{jj}x_j^2 - 2\sum_{i,j} A_{i,j} x_ix_j.$$

Now relabel $j$ as $i$ in the second  sum to get

$$\sum_{i,j} A_{i,j} (x_i-x_j)^2 = 2\sum_{i} D_{ii}x_i^2  - 2\sum_{i,j} A_{i,j} x_ix_j.$$

The right hand side is exactly $2 x^T(D-A)x^T$, and the graph Laplacian is $L=D-A$ (here $D$ is the diagonal matrix with entries $D_{ii}$).